# CakePHP Containable Behaviour limit Intermediate Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

CakePHP I am using containable behaviour but I have doubt to stop the data from the intermediate model.

SUppose I have this structure

```
Song -> Tracklist -> Album
```

So when I put `Containable` behavior on `Song Model` it fetch out Album data with desired field. But in every call it also fetch whole data of intermediate model Tracklist.

My containable behaviour is like this.

```
$contain =  array('Tracklist'=>array('Album'=>array('id','name')));
$this-Song->find('first', array('contain'=>$contain));
```

Like this. My data is like

```
 [Tracklist] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50
                [album_id] => 229
                [song_id] => 38
                [video_link] => 
                [status] => 0
                [featured] => 0
                [user_id] => 
                [created] => 
                [modified_by] => 
                [modified] => 
                [Album] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Marasim
                        [slug] => marasim
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2748
                [album_id] => 489
                [song_id] => 38
                [video_link] => 
                [status] => 1
                [featured] => 0
                [user_id] => 
                [created] => 2013-10-09 17:58:53
                [modified_by] => 
                [modified] => 2013-10-09 17:58:53
                [Album] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Dummy Album
                        [slug] => dummy-album
                    )

                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2749
                [album_id] => 489
                [song_id] => 38
                [video_link] => 
                [status] => 1
                [featured] => 0
                [user_id] => 
                [created] => 2013-10-09 17:59:42
                [modified_by] => 
                [modified] => 2013-10-09 17:59:42
                [Album] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Dummy Album
                        [slug] => dummy-album
                    )
            )
     )
```

I just want to limit data from intermediate Model. Is that possible ?

Comment: I have the same problem... Hope someone has the magic to stop the intermediate model from being fetch. :(

Comment: You dont want to retrieve Album data, right ?

Comment: @Moyed: I don't want to retrieve intermediate model means My data should be in the way `Tracklist->0->Album->AlbumData`. Like this.. What shall I do to fetch specific data from Tracklist or none from Tracklist Like this way (`Tracklist->0('id', 'album_id')->Album->AlbumData`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  $contain =  array('Tracklist'=>array(
        'fields' = array('id'),
        'Album'=>array('id','name')
  ));
  $this-Song->find('first', array('contain'=>$contain));
```

Comment: Though I tried same but it fetches some fields of the Intermediate Model those are linking to other Association. Means if my relationship is like `Tracklist->0->Album->` then it will surely fetch data like this `Tracklist->0('album_id')->Album->AlbumData`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this-Song->find('first', array('contain'=>$contain));

// Extract the Album's of the playlist
$data = Hash::extract($data, '{n}.Tracklist.Album');

// debug($data)
[Album] => Array (
                    [name] => Marasim
                    [slug] => marasim
                 )
...
```

If this is not exactly the output you want, put me a example of how do you want it, i will edit my answer. :)